# bash ${variable^^} fails when sourcing script

Tags: bash

I want to uppercase a variable in bash; I have version 4.4.12(1) installed and therefore am using the `${variable^^}` syntax.

Simple test script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $(bash --version)
words="test string"
uppercase_words=${words^^}
echo "words '${words}' uppercased '${uppercase_words}'"
```

When running from bash (`bash case_test` or just `./case_test`), it works:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0) Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
words 'test string' uppercased 'TEST STRING'
```

When source'ing the file (`source case_test`), it throws "bad substitution":

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0) Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
-bash: ${words^^}: bad substitution
words 'test string' uppercased ''
```

What the heck is going on here? It acts like it's getting an old version of bash, but as you can see, the version shows the same for either scenario. I'm on macOS Sierra, using brew to get the latest versions of bash.

**UPDATE and FIXED**:
The comments about $BASH_VERSION and source operation (thanks @Gordon & @Charles) were the key here. I had been depending on the sh-bang statement to handle things, but source doesn't use sh-bang.

I fixed the problem by changing my shell to the brew version through the `chsh` command.

Comment: `echo $(bash --version)` is not `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`

Comment: `$(bash --version)` is telling us which version of bash it **would** start if it were invoking a separate interpreter from the PATH, not which version of bash it's actually running right now.

Comment: ...presumably, the shell you're `source`ing it into is your 3.x release.

Comment: Your code works fine on 4.4.12(1) so it's got to be something with your shell. instead of running your script, do `echo $BASH_VERSION` and make sure that your shell isn't something else.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Yep; that was the issue, but I don't understand why sourcing the file ignores the sh-bang statement.

Comment: @JESii From [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins): `source: read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current shell context`. *In the current shell context* is the important part.

Comment: `source` always ignores the shebang. It has to, since `source` runs the script in the current shell, there's no way it could switch to the shell specified in the shebang. The shebang is used only if you run the script just by its filename or path, not when you run it with `sh filename` or `bash filename` or `source filename` or anything like that.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - but the "current shell" is a 4.4.12 version

Comment: @JESii Are you sure? What does `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` print?

Comment: @JESii, ...a transcript showing `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` immediately followed by the `source` command with the failure being run in the same terminal would be helpful, here, if you want to provide support for the case at hand.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Davisson & Charles Duffy -- both your comments steered me towards the solution. Updated the post.